# Azure - Automatic data import from csv to Storage explorer table

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure, trying to import a csv file into a table under Azure Storage Explorer. It works fine and could see the data imported.

Now, i would like to automate this process. I want Azure to read the data from Blob storage, add few headers and load the data into Azure Table Storage. Could you please tell me how this can be done? I have my csv file in local directory.

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-importexport-data-9458fa47

Comment: Thank you. It has details about exporting table to csv but i am looking for csv to table import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.
1. You can create an azure scheduled job that will contain code that parses CSV and uploads to Azure table storage
or
2. You can create an [Azure function app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/) that can do this.